# dplyr join and keeping variable obs without NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `for` loop that allocates portfolios based on `tdata$me` and a 10% quantile.  The issue I'm having is when I run the `for` loop, I end up only have the last observation year with the allocated portfolios.  As I loop through the years, the idea is to place the portfolio allocations `portf` and then join it with the larger dataset.

My question is how can I join two data sets without placing `NA` in all the other unknown obs and instead keeps the obs as is?

Also, is there a better way to run this `for` loop with `dplyr`?  This seems like an inefficient way to allocate portfolios, but I couldn't think of another way.

Reproducible Example :

```
tdata <- structure(list(cusip = c(47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
    47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L), 
    fyear = c(1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 
    1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1971L, 1971L, 1971L, 1971L, 
    1971L, 1971L, 1971L, 1971L), me = c(157,115,  45,  19, 132,  21, 147,
    191,  80, 165,  32, 100,  44, 134, 104,9, 183, 163, 109,  88), month = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    8L)), .Names = c("cusip", "fyear", "me", "month"), row.names = c(NA, 
    20L), class = "data.frame")

for(i in unique(tdata$fyear)){
  check <- filter(tdata, month == 06 & fyear == i)                         ###
  per <- quantile(check$me, c(.10, .20, .30, .40, .50, .60, .70, .80, .90))
  check$portf[check$me < per[[1]]] <- "A"
  check$portf[check$me >= per[[1]] & check$me < per[[2]]] <- "B"
  check$portf[check$me >= per[[2]] & check$me < per[[3]]] <- "C"
  check$portf[check$me >= per[[3]] & check$me < per[[4]]] <- "D"
  check$portf[check$me >= per[[4]] & check$me < per[[5]]] <- "E"
  check$portf[check$me >= per[[5]] & check$me < per[[6]]] <- "F"
  check$portf[check$me >= per[[6]] & check$me < per[[7]]] <- "G"
  check$portf[check$me >= per[[7]] & check$me < per[[8]]] <- "H"
  check$portf[check$me >= per[[8]] & check$me < per[[9]]] <- "I"
  check$portf[check$me >= per[[9]]]  <- "J"
  check <- select(check, cusip, fyear, portf)
  testcrsp <- left_join(tdata, check, by = c("cusip", "fyear"))  ######
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're rewriting `testcrsp` with every iteration

Comment: @Buckminster Yes that's it, but I'm not sure how to get this working where it merges all the loops together

Comment: Can you post an example of what your desired output is?

Comment: @Buckminster If you run the code above, you'll see that there are only portfolio allocations for 1971 where 1970 has NA.  A desired output would be there are 1970 portfolio allocations also

Comment: I'm trying to reduce your code but your example doesn't look very good. You end up with only one row, which results in all quantiles equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

A `dplyr` solution to remove the `for` loop. Note I removed the `length()` part because I'm not sure how to do that on `dplyr` without repeating the `breaks` code. The result is slightly different as it only returns a dataframe with `months==6` instead of all the data with `NA` for unselected months.

```
tdata3 <- tdata %>% group_by(fyear) %>%
  filter(month==6) %>% 
  mutate(portf = cut(me, labels=LETTERS[1:10], include.lowest=TRUE, breaks=(me %>% quantile(seq(0, 1, by=0.1)) %>% unique)) %>%      
  as.character) %>% ungroup
```

**Original**:

Here's what I think you wanted. It doesn't use `dplyr` since you don't need it to simply subset and loop through the years. It does use `cut` to split the `me` column quantiles into factors of letters.

```
tdata2 <- tdata
for (i in unique(tdata$fyear)) {
  thisyear <- tdata[tdata$fyear==i & tdata$month==6,]
  per <- unique(quantile(thisyear$me, seq(0, 1, by=0.1))) 
  factors <- cut(thisyear$me, breaks=per, labels=LETTERS[1:(length(per)-1)], include.lowest=TRUE)  
  tdata2$portf[tdata$fyear==i & tdata$month==6] <- as.character(factors)
}

tdata2
#    cusip fyear  me month portf
# 1     47  1970 157     6     I
# 2     47  1970 115     6     F
# 3     47  1970  45     6     C
# 4     47  1970  19     6     A
# 5     47  1970 132     6     G
# 6     47  1970  21     6     A
# 7     47  1970 147     6     H
# 8     47  1970 191     6     J
# 9     47  1970  80     6     D
# 10    47  1970 165     6     J
# 11    47  1970  32     6     B
# 12    47  1970 100     6     E
# 13    47  1971  44     6     B
# 14    47  1971 134     6     G
# 15    47  1971 104     6     D
# 16    47  1971   9     6     A
# 17    47  1971 183     6     J
# 18    47  1971 163     6     I
# 19    47  1971 109     6     E
# 20    47  1971  88     8  <NA>

# 0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%  100% 
#    A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
```

Note that unique has to be used in the quantiles because you could (it happened before you edited the data) have equal quantiles which won't be accepted as `breaks` for the factors. Also because of that you should use `length(per)` instead if directly typing `1:10`.

Comment: Thanks.  I just learned about using `cut` and also like your use of `dplyr`